# Adam prophesied Christ & Church marriage?

Tags: catholicism, genesis, marriage, prophecy, adam

Robert Grosseteste argues that Adam prophesied the mystical marriage of Christ with the Chirch in [Genesis 2:24](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=2&l=24-#x) and [Ephesians 5:32](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=56&ch=5&l=32-#x) ([Hunter, *If Adam Had Not Sinned*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8901) 2020, pp. 93-4):

> Adam prophesied, before his fall, the marriage of Christ and the church, saying, "Therefore a man shall leave his father and mother and will cleave to his wife, and there will be two in one flesh." About this the Apostle said, "This great mystery is of Christ and the church." [...] while knowing and believing nothing about the sin of the human race, which was to come, he believed in the marriage of Christ and the church.
>
> <sup>*DCL* III.1.20; p. 127, 3–6: "Item, Adam ante lapsum suum prophetavit matrimonium Christi et ecclesiæ, dicens: *Quamobrem relinquet homo patrem et matrem et ad­ herebit uxori sue; et erunt duo in carne una.* De quo dicit apostolus: *Sacramentum est hoc magnum in Christo et ecclesia*." [...] *DCL* III.1.20; p. 127, 13–15: "Nihil igitur de peccato humani generis quod esset futurum sciens vel credens, credidit matromonium Christi et ecclesiæ."</sup>

Is this a common interpretation of [Genesis 2:24](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=1&ch=2&l=24-#x) and [Ephesians 5:32](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=56&ch=5&l=32-#x), or did other Church fathers or doctors hold this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

St. Augustine, [*Tractates on the Gospel of John*, tractate 9](https://www.newadvent.org/fathers/1701009.htm).10 ([John 2:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=50&ch=2&l=1-#x)-2):

> Adam sleeps, that Eve may be formed; Christ dies, that the Church may be formed. When Adam sleeps, Eve is formed from his side; when Christ is dead, the spear pierces His side, that the mysteries may flow forth whereby the Church is formed.